# Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/getPublicUrlOrPath'

Tags: reactjs, heroku, npm, create-react-app

I have a React.js app which I've deployed on Heroku. Then I have this message:

> Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`.

So, I run `npm update` and `npm audit fix`. When pushing to Heroku again, I get this err :

> Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/getPublicUrlOrPath'

This is what I got when running `git push heroku master`:

```
remote: -----> Buildremote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > products-management@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_3b9104b8c72e292510eb4a5bd0494704
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
remote:   throw err;
remote:   ^
remote: 
remote: Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/getPublicUrlOrPath'
remote: Require stack:
remote: - /tmp/build_3b9104b8c72e292510eb4a5bd0494704/node_modules/react-scripts/config/paths.js
remote: - /tmp/build_3b9104b8c72e292510eb4a5bd0494704/node_modules/react-scripts/config/env.js
remote: - /tmp/build_3b9104b8c72e292510eb4a5bd0494704/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js
remote:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
remote:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
remote:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
remote:     at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_3b9104b8c72e292510eb4a5bd0494704/node_modules/react-scripts/config/paths.js:13:28)
remote:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
remote:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
remote:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
remote:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19) {
remote:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
remote:   requireStack: [
remote:     '/tmp/build_3b9104b8c72e292510eb4a5bd0494704/node_modules/react-scripts/config/paths.js',
remote:     '/tmp/build_3b9104b8c72e292510eb4a5bd0494704/node_modules/react-scripts/config/env.js',
remote:     '/tmp/build_3b9104b8c72e292510eb4a5bd0494704/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js'
remote:   ]
remote: }
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! products-management@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the products-management@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.qnMyP/_logs/2020-05-07T07_23_33_937Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:          https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
remote:        
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app. 
remote:  !     Push failed`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 8):

try using

```
npm install --save-dev react-dev-utils
```

it worked for me every time

Answer (score 4):

While not on Heroku, I also had a similar issue with the same `getPublicUrlOrPath` error. I tried npm-install multiple times and got a 404 error from a bad dependency, so I deleted it from package.json, removed the file package-lock.json, then ran `npm install --save` and all worked fine afterwards.

Comment: Had this problem after running `npm audit fix --force`. This answer fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue after running `npm audit fix --force` and this  command ended up creating in package.json under devDependency:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "compression-webpack-plugin": "^8.0.0",
  "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.0",
  "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.3",
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.1"
}
```

To solve the issue:

1. I removed node_modules, package.json.
2. Removed other dependencies created under devDependency and left only:

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
     "compression-webpack-plugin": "^8.0.0"
   }
   ```
3. lastly I ran `npm install --force`

That solved my problem on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue because the server had a different version of node than I had installed locally. I added "n 16.17.0" to checkout the expected version on the server and the error went away.